# Are there performance guides for iOS and Android browsers?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, css

As a web developer I also have to take the Android and iOS web browsers into account. The rendering engines of these browsers and the lack of power and memory brings a lot of complications.

So I was wondering, is there a comprehensive guide on performance tuning (HTML/CSS/Javascript) for these browsers?

Comment: I gave you an upvote and fav'd the question, I'm interested in the answer too. Meanwhile, here's a good resource for javascript mobile optimization that helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264307/what-techniques-can-i-use-to-make-js-heavy-pages-performant-on-mobile-devices/8264467#8264467

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found an actual guide focusing on mobile development yet. However, my coding practice is to do everything you'd do for a desktop browser and try to put extra effort in:

- maximize use of cache, by using CDN, ETags, proper expiry dates etc.
- minimize reflows/repaints, they are CPU intensive
- optimize images aggressively to minimize download size.
- minimze amount of server round-trips and included JS/CSS, since most mobiles are used on 3G/4G and other wireless networks. They tend to have higher latencies than wired broadband (cable/dsl).
- do not use animated gif, 3d transforms, etc.

Here is some reading material: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rules_intro